# How can I my JavaScript code be improved

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I make a request to a url, which returns an array of ***`JSON`***, and I put in my ***`HTML`*** like this:

---

```
$('#pesquisarServicos').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var parametro = document.getElementById('pesquisarServico').value;
  $.get("http://localhost:8080/service/list/"+parametro)
    .done(function (data) {
        var idServico, dataEntradaServico, dataSaidaServico, cpfPessoa, idStatus, descricaoServico;
        var tabela = "<tr> <td>idServico</td> <td>dataEntradaServico</td> <td>dataSaidaServico</td>" + 
        "<td>cpfPessoa</td> <td>idStatus</td> <td>descricaoServico</td> </tr>"
        for (var i in data) {
            idServico = data[i]["idServico"];
            dataEntradaServico = data[i]["dataEntradaServico"];
            dataSaidaServico = data[i]["dataSaidaServico"];
            cpfPessoa = data[i]["cpfPessoa"];
            idStatus = data[i]["idStatus"];
            descricaoServico = data[i]["descricaoServico"];
            tabelaResultado.innerHTML += tabela.replace("idServico", idServico).replace("dataEntradaServico", dataEntradaServico)
            .replace("dataSaidaServico", dataSaidaServico).replace("cpfPessoa", cpfPessoa).replace("idStatus", idStatus)
            .replace("descricaoServico", descricaoServico);
        }
    });
});
```

### But I think it's very ugly and I would like to improve this code.

I also wanted to ask, when I search a record it puts it on the right screen, but when I do another search it puts the answer down...

> How can I edit this code forever when I search to return only the
>   search result, and take the old research?

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about refactoring working code are more appropriately asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. This site is dedicated to non working code problems

Comment: well you can add `id`s to your elements, and then update them by `id` using jQuery (`$("#myId").text(data[i].whatever);`).

Answer (score 0):

When i have to create html in js i do something like this. Salve mano, vi que vc é br pelo nome das variavel.

```
var trHTML = "<tr>";
        trHTML += "<td>"+data[i]["idServico"]+"</td>";
        trHTML += "<td>"+data[i]["dataEntradaServico"]+"</td>";
            .
            .
            .
     trHTML += "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use template literals

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

instead of using `.replace` as it's expensive also the template literals will make you `html` more readable

```
$('#pesquisarServicos').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var parametro = document.getElementById('pesquisarServico').value;
  $.get("http://localhost:8080/service/list/"+parametro)
    .done(function (data) {
        var idServico, dataEntradaServico, dataSaidaServico, cpfPessoa, idStatus, descricaoServico;

        for (var i in data) {
            idServico = data[i]["idServico"];
            dataEntradaServico = data[i]["dataEntradaServico"];
            dataSaidaServico = data[i]["dataSaidaServico"];
            cpfPessoa = data[i]["cpfPessoa"];
            idStatus = data[i]["idStatus"];
            descricaoServico = data[i]["descricaoServico"];
            tabelaResultado.innerHTML +=`
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>${idServico}</td>
                                            <td>${dataEntradaServico}</td>
                                            <td>${dataSaidaServico}</td>
                                            <td>${cpfPessoa}</td>
                                            <td>${idStatus}</td>
                                            <td>${descricaoServico}</td>
                                        </tr>`;
        }
    });
});
```